# Linux RHEL how to differentiate between a local disk and a SAN disk

Tags: storage, linux, hard-drive

I have a server with several disks and partitions. For an specific disk I want to know if it is local or in the SAN.

I ran some commands:

```
[root@server]# ls -l /sys/block/*/device
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Jul 22 12:15 /sys/block/hda/device -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.1/ide0/0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Jul 22 12:15 /sys/block/sda/device -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:0e.0/host0/target0:2:0/0:2:0:0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Jul 22 12:15 /sys/block/sdb/device -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:0e.0/host0/target0:2:1/0:2:1:0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Jul 22 12:15 /sys/block/sdc/device -> ../../devices/platform/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0
```

How can I certainly know which device is local and which is connected to the SAN?

Answer (score 5):

There's a couple different approaches you can take. Some may be better or worse for your particular setup. Remember, strictly speaking a Fibre Channel drives does not necessarily mean "SAN" or "Storage Array". It may just be an actual FC-attached drive.

---

You can check to see which SCSI host the drive is on and filter that way if you know, for example, that all your servers have (i.e) QLogic cards:

```
# lsscsi -H; lsscsi -g
[0]    qla2xxx       
[1]    qla2xxx       
[2]    mptsas        
[3]    ata_piix      
[4]    ata_piix      
[0:0:0:0]    disk    IBM      1814      FAStT  0916  /dev/sda  /dev/sg0
[0:0:0:1]    disk    IBM      1814      FAStT  0916  /dev/sdb  /dev/sg1
[0:0:0:2]    disk    IBM      1814      FAStT  0916  /dev/sdd  /dev/sg3
[0:0:0:31]   disk    IBM      Universal Xport  0916  -         /dev/sg4
[1:0:0:0]    disk    IBM      1814      FAStT  0916  /dev/sdc  /dev/sg2
[1:0:0:1]    disk    IBM      1814      FAStT  0916  /dev/sde  /dev/sg5
[1:0:0:2]    disk    IBM      1814      FAStT  0916  /dev/sdf  /dev/sg6
[1:0:0:31]   disk    IBM      Universal Xport  0916  -         /dev/sg7
```

---

Check the `di` VPD page for the device in question to see what protocol it's using.

```
# sg_vpd -p di /dev/sda
Device Identification VPD page:
  Addressed logical unit:
    designator type: NAA,  code_set: Binary
      0x600a0b80002664e2000026c349dda1ee
  Target port:
    designator type: NAA,  code_set: Binary
     transport: Fibre Channel (FCP-2)
      0x200600a0b8266f7f
    designator type: Relative target port,  code_set: Binary
     transport: Fibre Channel (FCP-2)
      Relative target port: 0x1
  Target device that contains addressed lu:
    designator type: NAA,  code_set: Binary
     transport: Fibre Channel (FCP-2)
      0x200600a0b8266f7e
```

---

Check using the path management tools for your particular storage array to see if the device is on that array. For example:

```
# sg_rdac /dev/sda
RDAC Legacy page
  Controller serial: 1T63717016
  Alternate controller serial: 1T64109650
  RDAC mode (redundant processor): alternate controller present; Dual active mode
  RDAC mode (alternate processor): alternate controller present; Dual active mode
  Quiescence timeout: 75
  RDAC option 0x6
  LUN Table:
    0: a a x x x x x x
    1: x x x x x x x x
    2: x x x x x x x x
    3: x x x x x x x x
```

versus:

```
# sg_rdac /dev/sda
invalid field in cdb (perhaps subpages or page control (PC) not supported)
```

Answer (score 0):

SAN LUNs don't present themselves as IDE drives.

Comment: So those are or are not LUNs?

Comment: That's actually an invalid question - LUNs are the logical unit number of a SCSI device. A single target can have more than one LUN (such as a tape drive/controller or storage array). What you should be asking is "is that a FC-connected disk on the SAN?"

Comment: ... but Chopper3 is correct. One indicator is that FC disks don't present as IDE.

Comment: @MikeyB No problem I'll change my question. Then another question would be how do I list storage devices that are not present as IDE?